# FlutterFlow to Firebase API connection error

Tags: flutter, firebase, api, google-cloud-functions, flutterflow

I'm trying to connect FlutterFlow to Firebase to make an app with ChatGpt
I saw a tutorial to connect but I have an error.
I'm trying to connect FlutterFlow to Firebase to make an app with ChatGpt
I saw a tutorial to connect but I have an error.

[image: Picture of error]

I tried to follow a tutorial on youtube, but it does not exist

Comment: You have to go to your firebase console, select firestore, and create your database

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you haven't created a Firestore database in your Firebase project yet, which is required for FlutterFlow to be able to connect to it.

As the error message says, go to the [Firestore panel](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/overview) in the Firebase console and create the database from there.